# Can a creature who's been Swallowed Whole attack the creature it's in other than cutting its way out?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, grapple

Can a creature swallowed by another creature with the [Swallow Whole (Ex)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Swallow-Whole-Ex-) ability try to damage the swallowing creature without trying to *cut its way out*?

> A swallowed creature keeps the grappled condition, while the creature that did the swallowing does not. A swallowed creature can try to cut its way free with any light slashing or piercing weapon (the amount of cutting damage required to get free is equal to 1/10 the creature’s total hit points), or it can just try to escape the grapple.

From the description above it seems that a swallowed creature does only have two options

1. cut its way out (with a light slashing or piercing weapon) or
2. escape the grapple

It seems normal that a creature that can do bludgeoning damage will not be able to cut its way out but why should it not be able to just *damage* the stomach/intestines? Or use a potion or magic item? If the swallowed creature is able to move and attack with a piercing weapon it seems that it should be able to do more.

Or is the statement not exclusive — can you also take the actions allowed for [grappled creatures](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-If-You-Are-Grappled)?

> you can take any action that doesn’t require two hands to perform, such as cast a spell or make an attack or full attack with a light or one-handed weapon against any creature within your reach, including the creature that is grappling you.

Comment: Fun thing to try! Throw a fireball in there and watch your DM's head start to implode as they try to logic out how you're rolling a DEX save when detonating a blast inside the creature's stomach! Hardcore rule lawyering sometimes needs to give way to simple logic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## It can, or the cutting part wouldn't work.

The Pathfinder rules are based on a list of things characters can normally do, such as using skills, or attacking. This list is not absolute. A spellcaster can also cast spells, or you can't use diplomacy on someone trying to kill you at the same time. However, any deviation from the general set of possibilities needs to be explicitly mentioned in the rules.

[Swallow Whole](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Swallow-Whole-Ex-) makes no mention of any sort of restrictions on the character, apart from him being grappled. Of course, being grappled itself imposes restrictions on what you can do, and the grappling rules are clear on what you can do [if you are grappled](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-If-You-Are-Grappled), including

> Instead of attempting to break or reverse the grapple, you can take any action that doesn’t require two hands to perform, such as cast a spell or make an attack or full attack with a light or one-handed weapon against any creature within your reach, including the creature that is grappling you.

Also take note about the description of cutting yourself free from Swallow Whole:

> A swallowed creature can try to cut its way free with any light slashing or piercing weapon (**the amount of cutting damage required to get free is equal to 1/10 the creature’s total hit points**), or it can just try to escape the grapple. The Armor Class of the interior of a creature that swallows whole is normally 10 + 1/2 its natural armor bonus, with no modifiers for size or Dexterity.

This is not a special type of action only available to swallowed characters (Note how it doesn't say things like "as a standard action"). It basically just states that instead of just hacking away at the monsters insides, you can use some weapons (i.e. light slashing or piercing ones) to cut more precisely, in order to cut yourself free.